# Looking for software that is able to idenify speech sluring and mispronunciaitons for a research project, preferably open source

Tags: open-source, speech-recognition, research

My research group is working on diagnosing dementia by analyzing a persons speech. The idea is to try and detect early symptoms like slurring and mispronunciations. I know there are some commercial api's that can give a pronunciation score like speechace. I was wondering if anyone had seen any github projects that had similar functionality.